# Ajax and EJS - Ajax call doesn't work on the next forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, ejs

I have a table that creates a form for each registered student, and each form button has different student IDs. [When I clicked on the button, I want the student's mongoDB ID and his/her name to display on the textbox on the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJonC.png)

Here's the EJS file:

```
<tbody>
    <% students.forEach(function(data) { %>
        <tr>
             <td>
                <form id="addGrades" action="/teacher/add-score/<%= data._id %>">
                    <button id="addScores" class="ui button" type="submit">
                        <%= data.lastName + ", " + data.firstName + ", " + data.middleName %>
                    </button>
                </form> //code continues
```

my Ajax script:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("submit", "#addGrades", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var addScore = $("#addGrades");
        $.ajax({
            url: addScore.attr("action"),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(result){
                var form = $("#studentDetails");
                var inputID = $("#studentID");
                var inputName = $("#studentName");
                inputID.val("");
                inputName.val("");
                inputID.val(result.foundStudent._id);
                inputName.val(result.studentName);
            }
        });
    });
```

And the Express route:

```js
router.get("/teacher/add-score/:id", function(req, res){
    var studentID = req.params.id;
    userModel.findById(studentID, function(err, foundStudent){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            var studentName = foundStudent.firstName + " " + foundStudent.middleName + " " + foundStudent.lastName;
            res.send({foundStudent: foundStudent, studentName: studentName});
        }
    })
});
```

**The problem is** when I click the first button of the first data(the first row with Nicolas), it works, but when I click the second data(the button with Darktower), it doesn't. So I tried removing the Ajax script and tried logging the results on the console, and it logs the correct data. So, the problem probably is in my Ajax script. I searched already on the web but none of them seems to work.

Comment: You seem to have duplicate html ids (studentName, studentID, etc).  That’s not going to work.  I would suggest using classes and locating elements relative to known elements.

Comment: oh God, didn't think of that. Thanks! I'll try it. I'm sorry for being not so observant. omg Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @James I tried but still the same :( But the next button executes the res.send

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

It's in my HTML structure. jQuery struggles to look for which button I'm clicking so I added a clicked class to the button that I've clicked and use it for jQuery.